# What's the name of this Rubik's Cube pattern, where each face has a main diagonal and an L on either side in three different colors respectively?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles

[image: pattern]

This pattern looks really interesting, but all I can find on it is this one picture.
If someone could also provide a video tutorial (if possible), because I don't really do well with notations.

Answer (score 6):

This is called the "Corner Pyramid".

It can be achieved with:

> U' D B R' F R B' L' F' B L F R' B' R F' U' D

You can find several [YouTube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=rubiks+cube+corner+pyramid+pattern) for this if you can't read notation.

Note: I found this on Ruwix. They have two nice pages of patterns [(1)](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/rubiks-cube-patterns-algorithms/) [(2)](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/rubiks-cube-patterns-algorithms/more-rubiks-patterns/), and this was on the second page.

Comment: I looked on ruwix several times but couldn’t find it thanks

Comment: @Scriptonix Glad to help! If my answer works for you, could you accept it?